# Related name not working for django many to many field django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to access the value of an object that holds the ManyToMany relationship, similar to a related name for a ForeignKey or a OneToOne.

How do I need to change my models to allow this?

This is my current **models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Account(models.Model):

    account_owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='account_owner')
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='account_profile')
```

When I try `{{ request.user.account_owner.account_name }}` I get the expected value of the account name (if they are the owner).

But when I try `{{ request.user.account_profile.account_name }}` I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike ForeignKey or a OneToOne, M2M returns a list.

So, I guessing you're trying to achieve this in your template.

Here is how you can

```
{% for member in request.user.account_profile.all %}
         {{ member.account_name }}
{% endfor %}
```